# Kerdi Membrane over cement backerboard

Tags: bathroom, shower, tile, backer-board, kerdi

When installing Schluter Kerdi Membrane over cement backerboard:

Should I use Alkali Resistant Mesh Tape and thinset on the seams of the backer board (*for long term durability to prevent each board moving independently thus preventing cracking*) prior to installing the Kerdi membrane. (*3ft-3in wide*)

Or will the Kerdi membrane (*with seams taped with kerdi band*) prevent each board from moving independently?

Comment: Why do you think each board should be able to move at all let alone  independently?

Comment: Why you use cement board?  The benefit of using kerdi is we can lay it over drywall

Answer (score 0):

If there is no blocking behind the seam, i would just tape prior to installing the membrane, the thinset will fill the seam and embed the mesh. The kerdi membrane will probably do the same, and its regularly installed over drywall which is probably less stable